# Postgres returning records when query result should be empty

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following,

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.user (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    chat_ids BIGINT[] NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.chat (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    chat_id_value BIGINT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_schema.chat VALUES
    (1, 12321);

INSERT INTO my_schema.user VALUES
    (1, '{12321}');
```

When I query for a user record with a nonexisting chat, I still receive a result:

```
SELECT u.id,
    (
        SELECT TO_JSON(COALESCE(ARRAY_AGG(c.*) FILTER (WHERE c IS NOT NULL), '{}'))
        FROM my_schema.chat as c
        WHERE c.chat_id_value = ANY (ARRAY[ 1234 ]::int[])
    ) AS chat_ids
FROM my_schema.user as u
```

Clearly, there is no `my_schema.chat` record with with `chat_id_value = 1234`.

I've tried adding,

```
. . .
FROM my_schema.user as u
WHERE chat_ids != '{}'
```

But this still yields the same result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "chat_ids": []
    }
]
```

I've tried `WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(chat_ids, 1) != 0`, `WHERE CARDINALITY(chat_ids) != 0`, none return the expected result.

Oddly enough, `WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(chat_ids, 1) != 1` works, implying the length of `chat_ids` is `1` when it's actually `0`? Very confusing.

What am I doing wrong here? The expected result should be `[]`.

Comment: You select all records from my_schema.user, and also try to create a json object. Where there is at least one record in this table, you get a result.

Comment: Correct, but then I specify `WHERE chat_ids != '{}'` and I still get the same result.

Comment: I've also tried `WHERE CARDINALITY(chat_ids) != 0`, but same issue

Comment: I don't get it. With your first query there is no result. Witch version are you using. Can you replicate on fiddle? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0

Comment: @user_0 Sure, here you go: https://dbfiddle.uk/6vv212U6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the subselect on `my_schema.chat` returns no result, you will get NULL, which `coalesce` will turn into `{}`. Moreover, the inner query is not correlated to the outer query, so you will get the same result for each row in `my_schema."user"`. You should use an inner join:

```
SELECT u.id,
       TO_JSON(COALESCE(ARRAY_AGG(c.*) FILTER (WHERE c IS NOT NULL), '{}'))
FROM my_schema.user as u
   JOIN my_schema.chat as c
      ON c.chat_id_value = ANY (u.chat_ids);
```

I don't think that your data model is good. You should avoid arrays and use a junction table instead. It will make for better performance and simpler queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding your note, is this what you mean? https://dbfiddle.uk/sPyoAMmh

Comment: Yes, except that the primary key for the junction table had best be on `(user_id, chat_id)`.

Comment: Is this correct? https://dbfiddle.uk/CMJDtpGC

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would suggest. I recommend using `bigint` and never `integer` for autogenerated primary keys. Identity columns are the modern replacement for `serial` and `bigserial`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(c.*) FILTER (WHERE c IS NOT NULL)) as to_json
  FROM my_schema.chat as c
  inner join  my_schema.user u on c.chat_id_value = ANY (u.chat_ids)
  WHERE c.chat_id_value = ANY (ARRAY[ 12321]::int[])
)
select * 
from cte where to_json is not null;
```

This will force not to show any result if the query don't match !

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BC3nlZF-)